# How does the Zebra "FB" command affect the "A" and "FO" commands

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl-ii

I'm trying to understand how the "FB" command works with regard to the "A" command.

Here's an example of a line of text being printed:

`^FO309,752^A0N,51,38^FWN^FH^FB490,,,R,^FD STANDARD OVERNIGHT^FS`

The "A" command sets the font to 'scalable" and the character width to 38 dots. The "FB" command says the width of the text block is 490 dots and is right-justified.

The text is 19 characters long (with the blank) and at 38 dots per character the total number of dots of " STANDARD OVERNIGHT" is 722 (19 * 38). That's greater that 490. So how does this work? Is something scaled up or down? What is the equation?

The Zebra manual states "While the ^FB command has a text justification parameter that defines the justification of the text within the block, it also interacts with the justification of ^FO and ^FT that define the justification of the origin."

How? There's no elaboration.

Thanks in advance,
Mike

I didn't "try" anything since I only want to understand what the Zebra printer does in this example.

Comment: Font-0 is a variable-width font.  Not every character is x-pixels wide.  For that matter, _most_ characters are less than x-pixels wide.  Your example text is rendering about 80% of the specified width.  Try decreasing width to say 350 and you will see the wrapping/overwriting behavior typical of the `^FB` command.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm asking how the Zebra printer figures it out.